# Creating dictionary from CSV file, dictionary not containing all values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

For the following CSV File:

```
A,B,C
-----
A1,B1,C1
A1,B2,C2
A2,B3,C3
A2,B4,C4
```

My dictionary currently looks like this:

```
{'A1': {'B':'B1', 'C':'C1'}, 'A2': {'B':'B3', 'C':'C3'}
```

How do I get my dictionary to look like this:

```
'A1': {'B': ['B1', 'B2'], 'C': ['C1', 'C2']}, 'A2': {'B': ['B3', 'B4'], 'C': ['C3', 'C4']}}
```

I'm using the following code at the moment:

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv'))

result = {}
for row in reader:
    key = row.pop('A')
    if key in result: pass
    result[key] = row
print result
```

Comment: Is the second one supposed to be a string?

Comment: @ayhan The key value (A) is a string, the second value (B) is a string, and the third value (C) is a number

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks I've made the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a base case for each key, such that the dictionary inserts the first value as a list. Then you can append values for duplicate keys as they are encountered.

The following code should do what you need:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for row in reader:
            key = row.pop('A')
            if '-' in key:
                    continue
            if key not in result:
                    new_row = {'B': [row.pop('B')], 'C': [row.pop('C')]}
                    result[key] = new_row
            else:
                    result[key]['B'].append(row.pop('B'))
                    result[key]['C'].append(row.pop('C'))
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million man! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use DictReader to achieve this. You can just use regular csv.reader and fill up your own dictionary.

Here is a commented simple solution:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv

csv_fpath = 'test.csv'
# readcsv.py

# You want this:
#{'A1': {'B':['B1','B2'], 'C':['C1','C2']}, 'A2': {'B':['B3','B4'], ..}}
mydict = {}
# newline = '' option is needed as per csv.reader documentation python 3.x
with open(csv_fpath, mode='r') as csvfile:
    # A regular csv reader object
    myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    # Header on first line
    hrow = next(myreader)
    # # Tagging header names for dictionary keys later
    taga, tagb, tagc = hrow[0], hrow[1], hrow[2]

    # Skip separator line (delete this line if unnecessary)
    next(myreader)

    # Reading data and constructing our dictionary
    for row in myreader:
        if len(row) == 0:
            # ignore blank lines
            continue
        # Each row's key is the first column value
        key = row[0]
        if key in mydict:
            # If an item exists with the given key, that item itself is also a
            # dictionary with lists in keys tagb and tagc. So we append to those
            # lists the values in second and third columns
            mydict[key][tagb].append(row[1])
            mydict[key][tagc].append(row[2])
        else:
            # Note the list constructors, they are important as we are going to
            # append them down the iteration
            mydict[key] = { tagb: [row[1]]
                          , tagc: [row[2]]}

print(mydict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open("test.csv"))

result = {}
for row in reader:
    if reader.line_num <= 2:
        continue
    key = row["A"]
    for subkey in [k for k in row.keys() if k != "A"]:
        if key not in result:
            result[key] = {}
        if subkey not in result[key]:
            result[key][subkey] = []
        result[key][subkey].append(row[subkey])

>>> print(result)
{'A2': {'C': ['C3', 'C4'], 'B': ['B3', 'B4']}, 'A1': {'C': ['C1', 'C2'], 'B': ['B1', 'B2']}}
```